# Running an Ant-builded project as web-application

Tags: eclipse, gwt, servlets, web-applications, ant

I'm trying to run a "project.zip" I've downloaded from the official GWT site about RPC and Hibernate  at http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html .

The guide suggests:

> "you can use Ant to build the project, as well as start up hosted mode
>   to see the UI and our Hibernate instance setup in the embedded Jetty
>   server."

So I have imported it on Eclipse with *New > Project menu-> Java Project from Existing Ant Buildfile* wizard.

My final goal is to run it on Eclipse as web-application, but it gives me every types of errors and above all there's no *run as-> web application* but only *as ->ant build* ! And all the War directory is missing in Eclipse.

How can change this Ant build project.zip to a normal project GWT? I'm amazed how an official Google guide can give so many problems!

If you need it this is the *build.xml* :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<project name="Guestbook" default="build" basedir=".">

    <!-- Define gwt.home, gwt.dev.jar, appengine.sdk.home -->
    <property file="build.properties"/>

    <path id="project.class.path">
        <pathelement location="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/gwt-user.jar"/>
        <!-- Add any additional non-server libs (such as JUnit) -->
        <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <target name="libs" description="Copy libs to WEB-INF/lib">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/lib" />
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" file="${gwt.home}/gwt-servlet.jar" />
        <!-- Add any additional server libs that need to be copied -->
        <copy todir="war/WEB-INF/lib" flatten="true">
            <fileset dir="lib/">
                <include name="**/*.jar"/>
            </fileset>
        </copy>
     </target>

      <target name="javac" depends="libs" description="Compile java source">
        <mkdir dir="war/WEB-INF/classes"/>
        <javac srcdir="src" includes="**" encoding="utf-8"
            destdir="war/WEB-INF/classes"
            source="1.5" target="1.5" nowarn="true"
            debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source">
            <classpath refid="project.class.path"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <!-- can add additional arguments like -logLevel INFO or -style PRETTY -->
    <target name="gwtc" depends="javac" description="GWT compile to JavaScript">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="src"/>
                <path refid="project.class.path"/>
                <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/${gwt.dev.jar}"/>
            </classpath>
            <!-- add jvmarg -Xss16M or similar if you see a StackOverflowError -->
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
            <arg value="com.google.musicstore.MusicStore"/>
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="hosted" depends="javac" description="Run hosted mode">
        <java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.HostedMode">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="src"/>
                <path refid="project.class.path"/>
                <pathelement location="${gwt.home}/${gwt.dev.jar}"/>
            </classpath>
            <jvmarg value="-Xmx256M"/>
            <arg value="-startupUrl"/>
            <arg value="MusicStore.html"/>
            <arg value="com.google.musicstore.MusicStore"/>
            <!-- Additional arguments like -style PRETTY or -logLevel DEBUG -->
        </java>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="gwtc" description="Build this project" />

    <target name="clean" description="Cleans this project">
        <delete dir="war/WEB-INF/classes" failonerror="false" />
        <delete dir="war/musicstore" failonerror="false" />
    </target>

</project>
```

Comment: did you run "ant build" ?

Comment: @smcg when i run "ant build" on terminal or run as->ant build in eclipse it gives me an very long error that i dont understand and the build fails after 1 second...this is the stacktrace : http://pastebin.com/KJanE7aY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

run

```
ant
```

to build the project.

run

```
ant hosted
```

to run the project.

I'm confused by the concept of a *normal GWT project* ... I'm not sure to understand what it means. But if it means an *eclipse-ready-GWT-project*, you will probably be disappointed because as you noted yourself:

> you can use Ant to build the project

It is an ant based project, not en eclipse project. You can call ant from eclipse, but there is no specic eclipse files (.project and .classpath) so that it can run with gwt eclipse plugin without configuring it yourself.

Comment: yeah I meant an eclipse-ready-GWT-project... so it isnt possible...the problem is that when I run "ant" on terminal or "run as->ant build" in eclipse it gives me an very long error and the build fails after 1 second...this is the stacktrace : pastebin.com/KJanE7aY

Comment: try to run it from command line (some libs required by the build are probably missing in the ant runtime classpath when it runs from eclipse. (other option, you made a wrong edit in some xml file ?)

Comment: Even if I run it by command line (as i said above on terminal) it gives me the same error of eclipse...The only thing I edited is the "build.properties" file where I setted the path of gwt.home and gwt.dev.jar that are used in the "build.xml" file...and I know they are correct because before of this it gives me errors of the wronged paths of jars

Comment: the top of the stacktrace is missing in your pastebin and that's where the root error is visible.

Comment: I found this in the trace : `[ERROR] Line 33: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
     [java] com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)` (are you sure that you are using the correct gwt version ?)

Comment: The javadoc for UnableToCompleteException is very explicit : a precise and meaningful error message must be logged before throwing the exception. So you must definively read the logs before the huge stacktrace to find the real cause of your problem. (ref : http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/ext/UnableToCompleteException.html)

Comment: Thank you @ben75 ! You have right, the message was so long that both the terminal and the eclipse console miss the begin! Now I've understood that was a problem of incompatibilty of jars versions and the build succeed!

Comment: But if i import the project to eclipse the war folder is missing. It's possible to import it too? And it's possible to run as GWT web application? @ben75

Comment: It's probably possible to run this app in eclipse if you do some manual configuration of the eclipse project (add gwt nature or something like that; setup build path ; ...). I'm not an eclipse expert so, it's difficult to explain precisely the required steps.